# jquery allow number field to accept multiple periods

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a number field in a form that I want to accept multiple periods. This field will be used for entering software version numbers. The code I have only allows for one period to be entered. Once I add two periods to the field I get an error. Here is the code I'm using.
I'm using a form builder. and can add Javascript and CSS. I cannot however edit the html or php

```
$('.decimal input').numeric({allow:"."}); 
<div class="decimal">
    <label class="description" >Version Number (must be a number) <span  class="required">*required</span></label>
    <div>
        <input class="element text small" type="text" value=""> 

    </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The error I get once i add two periods is "This field must be a number"

Comment: He is using [numeric.js](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/numeric/)

Comment: @nicban could you post your html and code for that function?

Comment: Don't use `numeric.js` for this. Version numbers aren't real numbers, and the plugin isn't intended for them. Write your own Javascript that uses a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that this code is incorrect. I'm new to writing regular expressions and was trying to avoid it. Guess I'll need to to solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use regex? It matches only numbers and any number of dots, but not in the beginning or end of string. Also two dots are not allowed next to each other.

```
var regex = /^(\*|\d+(\.\d+)*(\.\*)?)$/i;
if (regex.test($('.decimal input'))) {
    // valid number
}
```

Comment: This ignores the fact that OP is attempting to use something (probably a plugin) called `numeric`.

Comment: @cale_b That's necessary, since the plugin is simply not intended for this purpose.

Comment: @cale_b He might as well be using a datepicker to validate numbers.

Comment: @Barmar - I agree (about datepicker)! And for clarity - I'm not suggesting the regex solution is incorrect, I'm suggesting that this answer does not speak to the problem with using `numeric` for validation.  Your comment (much later in the game, on the question), does more to help clarify than this answer does *as long as it doesn't mention numeric*.  I'm just trying to nudge these people to crafting stronger answers.